# how to track users with websocket++ 0.3X

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, sessionid, websocket++

Is there a way to track per user data with websocket++ 0.3X?

I want to be able to identify them so to keep track of what they're looking at and what should be sent to them.  Take stack as an example: while you're looking at this question, a websocket could (and I think *does*) keep in memory that you're looking at this question and send you the appropriate updates like votes, new comments & answers, and StackExchange updates in the upper left corner.

Also, the users need to be able to identified.  Is there a session id inherent in websockets that are already hiding in websocket++?  If not, how does websocket++ track users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is, as you mentioned in your answer, to use connection_hdl as a key for an associative container that stores any other data you need. WebSocket++ does have some other options for cases where that sort of lookup would be too costly.

Since this is a common question, I've written up some more formal examples & documentation on how to do this here: http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/common-patterns/storing-connection-specificsession-information.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, OK.  It was hiding in plain sight all along.  http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/building-program-websocket

> The connection handle is a token that uniquely identifies the
>   connection that received the message. It can be used to identify where
>   to send reply messages or stored and used to push messages later. The
>   type of the connection handle is websocketpp::connection_hdl.